# bootstrap sticky-top class does work properly (used with django)

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, sticky

i have a bootstrap navbar with  a sticky-top class it's works for about 200px scroll but when i pass that 200px limit  it does not work , the thing is when a use the navbar with  the bootstrap starter template ( no local server just  html ) it works  but when use it whit django  and i run my sever it does not work

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% include 'head.html' %}
<body>
{% include 'header.html' %}
{% block content %}

{% endblock content %}


{% include 'footer.html' %}
{% include 'scripts.html' %}
</body>

</html>
```

**head.html:**

```
{% load static %}
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="robots" content="all,follow">
 <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap-4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'swiper-5.3.7/package/css/swiper.min.css' %}">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f057e2fa03.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'vendor/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css' %}"> 
 <!-- Google fonts - Open Sans-->

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 

 <!-- theme stylesheet-->
 <!-- Custom stylesheet - for your changes-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}">
<!-- semantic UI -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.14/semantic.min.css">
<!--Chart js-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha256-Uv9BNBucvCPipKQ2NS9wYpJmi8DTOEfTA/nH2aoJALw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.css" integrity="sha256-aa0xaJgmK/X74WM224KMQeNQC2xYKwlAt08oZqjeF0E=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<!--braintree-->
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.22.1/js/dropin.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

**header.html**

```
{% url 'home' as home_url %}
{% url 'products_list' as products_url %}
  <!-- navbar phone -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top d-block d-md-none">
  <div class="container px-0">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">YouShirt</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: have you checked by inspecting from browser? any other class may be overriding it?, most of the time i get fixes from there itself, just thinking out loud

Comment: @AchintyaRanjanChaudhary  .sticky-top {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1020;
}  the first property has an exclamation mark  on it  ,what does it means ?